# Why is this accordion allowing for multiple tabs to be open at once

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I only want one tab to be open at a time and I do not understand what I am missing.  Thanks in advance

```
<div id="Accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true"> 
    <a href="#firstSection" id="firstHeading" role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Accordion" aria-controls="firstSection" aria-expanded="true"> 
        First header
    </a>
    <div class="collapse in" aria-labeledby="#firstHeading" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" id="firstSection">
        first content
    </div> 
    <hr/>

    <a class="collapsed" href="#secondSection" id="secondSectionHeading" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" data-parent="#Accordion" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="secondSection">
       second header
    </a>

    <div class="collapse" aria-labeledby="#secondSectionHeading" role="tabpanel" id="secondSection">
        second content
    </div>
    <hr/>

    <a class="collapsed" href="#thirdSection" id="thirdSectionHeading" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" data-parent="#Accordion" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="thirdSection">
        third header
    </a>

    <div class="collapse" aria-labeledby="#thirdSectionHeading" role="tabpanel" id="thirdSection">
        third content
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Link here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfakey/2vaubepa/2/)

EDIT: updated fiddle

Answer (score 0):

The tabs can not work if you do not attach some javascript to them. Also your markup is not properly set!
I have added below a link to jsFiddle for a working example to get you started.

Comment: You completely changed everything I did.  Here is an example of this working correctly without .js

http://jsfiddle.net/jfakey/1nkf5pgt/1/

Comment: Sorry !! My Bad!! I gave you an example for tabs, while you where asking something about accordions.

Comment: I am glad you solve your problem!! In my place is 4:00 in the night and maybe I am a little sleepy.

Comment: It is not solved.  I used the example from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse ...but this is not what I need.  Thanks a bunch for the help though

Comment: What you need actually?

Comment: only one accordion panel to be open at a time

Comment: If you still need help please let me know. I will be glad to help you out.

Comment: But this is what you already  have done in fiddle from the bootstrap exmple. Do you stritcly need to keep your code as it is?